# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, poo, firestore

Estoy creando una coleccion en firebase en donde necesito insertar un objeto con unos valores, pero cuando intento agregarlo me genera este error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function, no entiendo a que se debe o en dado caso como podria insertar yo mi objeto dentro de la coleccion de firebase.

Este es el codigo donde tengo mi objeto:

```
const consultValues = async () => {
    const resApi = await getData();
    const consultApiSelectionRow = resApi.map((el) => {
      const convertObjectToArray = Object.entries(el);
      return convertObjectToArray.filter((key) =>
        key.includes(ArrayOfSelectedButtons[0])
      );
    });
    const consultApiSelectionColumn = resApi.map((el) => {
      const convertObjectToArray = Object.entries(el);
      return convertObjectToArray.filter((key) =>
        key.includes(ArrayOfSelectedButtons[1])
      );
    });
    const consultApiSelectionValues = resApi.map((el) => {
      const convertObjectToArray = Object.entries(el);
      return convertObjectToArray.filter((key) =>
        key.includes(ArrayOfSelectedButtons[2])
      );
    });
    return (apiConsultation = {
      filas: consultApiSelectionRow,
      columnas: consultApiSelectionColumn,
      valores: consultApiSelectionValues,
    });
  };
```

esta es la funcion de firebase :

```
/*Creando coleccion de tablas*/
export const createColectionTable = async (obj) => {
 addDoc(collection(db, 'tables', { obj }))
}
```

asi le paso el objeto a la coleccion

```
const generateReport = async () => {
  const valuesForTable = await consultValues();
  createColectionTable(valuesForTable);
};
```

Esta es mi función getData, aqui consulto a mi api:

```
export const getData = async () => {
 const config = {
   method: 'get',
   url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/cubo/api/ventas?empresa=63&periodo=202202',
   headers: {
     'token': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
   }
 };

 const response = await axios(config);
 const responseData = await response.data.data;
 return responseData
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Creo que el error está dentro de la función `getData`

Comment: @PabloLozano getData es donde consumo mi api y ahi no tengo error.

Comment: El error dice que el problema es cuando se intenta llamar a `indexOf`. El código que has puesto no tiene esa llamada, por tanto el error no está ahí. El error es dentro de una promesa, así que o es dentro de `getData()` o `consultValues()`. El error también suele indicar en qué fichero y línea ocurre

Comment: @PabloLozano PEro es que en ninguna de las dos funciones llamo a indexOf. Voy  editar y colocar mi funcion getData para que lo veas.

Comment: Puedes poner todo el mensaje de error, creo que ayudará

Comment: @pablo lozano edite la pregunta y agregue la imagen donde se muestra el error tambien hice un console.log con lo que estoy intentando agregar a la colección para que veas como esta estructurado mi objeto.

Comment: Es dentro de createCollectionTable